# Special Url for Jekyll out of Base URL

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I am using jekyll to setup my blog.

```
# Site Settings
baseurl:            "/blog" # Base URL must end WITHOUT a slash, default: ""
```

My site `baseurl` setting is /blog.

I want to redirect or show a specific page to users when they reach "/".
now it just shows 404.

is there any way i can configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your blog is in the `github.com/userName/blog` reporitory, it can be reached at `username.github.io/blog/`.

If you try to reach `username.github.io/` and you get a 404, you need to create an index page in your `github.com/userName` repository.